# Phoenix - recompile local dependency on file change without server restart

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm developing a library for Phoenix. I have created a Phoenix project with mix.exs:

```elixir
defp deps do
  [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
  ...
  {:my_package, path: "../my_package"}]
end
```

and I want Phoenix to automatically recompile that dependency when I change it, without restarting a Phoenix server. Is it possible? I have already tried installing [remix](https://github.com/AgilionApps/remix) to both Phoenix and my_package and adding `~r{../my_package/lib/.*(ex)$}` in `live_reload` Phoenix config, but nothing works.

Comment: Is it possible to put both projects inside of an umbrella project?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ to me it smells like an SRP violation. I think, `my_package` should be produced and tested separately, otherwise you sooner or later end up with unresolved cross-dependencies;, preventing of using the package inside other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Justin Wood said - umbrella project is the answer. I put `my_package` and my phoenix app inside umbrella project, now phoenix refreshes (and compiles) page each time I change something in `my_package`. More:

https://gist.github.com/emilsoman/9bdabbfe873ef28358d83eaa11d45024

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html